# Is there a possibility of choosing the predetermined alias from a gmail account to send mails from apps Scripts when you have more than a group?

Tags: google-apps-script

I've a script that send emails from different accounts and it's send by the alias from that account. The problem is that i've to send it from the email that alias is predeterminated in the account and when y choose 'from: Alias[0]' in the GmailApp, not always the predeterminated is the 0.

Is there any other possibility to send it from the alias predeterminated directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Gmail API, more specifically the [REST Resource users.settings.sendAs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.sendAs#SendAs) (I'm don't know if this is possible with the Advanced Gmail Service). For this you will have to use the URL Fetch Service (Class UrlFetchApp)

Related

- [Creates a custom "from" send-as alias with GAS and APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49700530/1595451)

Comment: Thanks Rubén for your answer. I'll try it and search more information about it.